# Do not update connection string with click once

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string, clickonce, app-config

I would like to deploy a WPF application with click once. But each of our customers use different connection strings.

I can not find a solution that does not crush the app.config when updating or move the app.config in a different directory then use when launching the application.

Someone there a solution?

Comment: adding user to database and corresponding connectionstring ?

Comment: the connection string corresponds exactly to the connection to the database. So I need to know from the start of the application.